# Matrix Creation and Assignment in Matlab

Tags: matlab, variable-assignment, matrix-indexing, replicate

I have two matrices A fixed size, B grows iterationwise. How to create matrix B of equal size as A, but to be enlarged/manipulated according to the vector 'j'. 
Cases 1) Size B< Size A, 2) Size B=Size A, 3) Size B> Size A. First case is critical.

```
A=rand(10,3)
B=rand(3,3)
i=1:10  % Order of rows in A
j=[2 1 3 1 1 3 2 1 3 1] % always random ordered by another subprogram
A(i,:)=B(j,:)
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. How to create B and A the same size? Just use the same values in your rand() function.

Comment: For display over here, I have shown A and B to be random matrices. B has to be matched to the size of B but rows of it are to be manipulated accrding to vector 'j'.

Comment: Ok I see what you mean. But I don't understand why you create a random A as all rows will be totally replaced.

Comment: See when A and B are equal then further matrix operations can be done. I have updated question. A is not changing, only B has to be enlarged.

Comment: Your question is still very unclear. You really need to explain more what you want to do and what does not work, put more code, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
A=zeros(10,3)
B=rand(3,3)
i=1:10  % Order of rows in A
j=[2 1 3 1 1 3 2 1 3 1] % always random ordered by another subprogram
%A(i,:)=B(j,:)
for i:1:10
    A(i,:) = B(j(i),:)
end
```

This works as long as the number of columns are the same in A and B. However the values in `j` should be only 1 and 2 as you only have 2 rows in B.

Comment: Just change B=rand(3,3)